# Spring JPA Date return type

Tags: spring, date, jpa, formatter

i made a method that need to return list of objects by jpa by Date enddate and i only got in return null, maybe its becouse i need to add time or date formatter but i dont know please help ty.

```
@GetMapping("/couponbyenddate/{companyid}/{enddate}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Coupon>> getCouponByEndDate(@PathVariable("enddate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") Date endDate ,HttpServletRequest req) throws ParseException {
        List<Coupon> couponsbyenddate = companyService.getCouponsByEndDate(getLoggedUser(req).getUserId(), endDate);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(couponsbyenddate,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
public List<Coupon> getCouponsByEndDate(int companyid, Date endDate) throws ParseException {
        List<Coupon>coupons = couponRepo.findCompanyCouponByendDate(companyid, endDate);
        System.out.println(coupons);
        return coupons;
    }
```

```
    @Query("SELECT c from Company as company join company.coupons As c WHERE company.id=:companyid AND c.endDate=:enddate")
    public List<Coupon> findCompanyCouponByendDate(int companyid, Date enddate);
```

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CouponType type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String msg;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String picture;
```

i got in return empty list [].

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html. Your Date attribute is supposed to be annotated with this annotation (but you should really avoid the obsolete Date class. Use java.time.LocalDate).

Comment: thnx its work ^^ by adding  
`@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
`

Comment: there is another problem with it now its lower 1 day from the date i create

Comment: Do you mean that you create an entity with a date, then read it from the database, and you don't obtain the same date? Or are you just having a timezone issue where the timezone of your JVM is not the same as the one used by your database? Have you switched to a LocalDate?

Comment: yes i changed but when i do that i cant use this function

`public boolean checkIfCouponExpired(Coupon coupon) {
  if (coupon.getEndDate().getTime() <= coupon.getStartDate().getTime()) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }`

becouse getTime() is not part of LocalDate

Comment: i need to use it in here setting the local date time

`if (checkIfCompanyExists(companyId)) {
    LocalDate couponCreatingDate = LocalDate.now();
    Date couponDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(couponCreatingDate);
    coupon.setStartDate(couponDate);
    couponRepo.save(coupon);`

Comment: Regarding the first comment: read the javadoc of LocalDate. It has methods allowing to compare LocalDate. And a LocalDate isn't an instant, so calling getTime() wouldn't make any sense. Regarding the second comment: stop using Date and java.sql.Date. Stick to java.time classes.